# Unable to pass variable to get wmi object query

Tags: powershell, sccm

Hope you could help me with my issue. I tried to import a list of packages to $list variable and a list of DP server to variable named $DP. I used foreach and write-host and have confirmed that all items in the variable are showing ok, but  when I use the variable in get-wmi object as parameter to filter the $i.packageid it is empty/null. Please advise how to resolve this.

sample code

```
$list=import-csv -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator\desktop\SCCM\packagelist.csv'
$DP="SCCMDP1","SCCMDP2"


foreach ($i in $list)
{

write-host "Item is $($i)"   # showing ok
write-host "package is $($i.package)" # showing ok
write-host "packageid is $($i.packageid)" # showing ok


get-wmiobject -namespace root\sms\site_v01 -class sms_distributiondpstatus -Filter {packageid like "$i.packageid"}|select name
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your variables differently in the parameters than from your `Write-Host` calls.  You can't access object properties without a subexpression in the string `$()`.

```
$list = import-csv -Path 'C:\Users\Administrator\desktop\SCCM\packagelist.csv'
$DP = 'SCCMDP1','SCCMDP2'

foreach ($i in $list)
{
    write-host "Item is $i"   # showing ok
    write-host "package is $($i.package)" # showing ok
    write-host "packageid is $($i.packageid)" # showing ok

    Params = @{
        Namespace = 'root\sms\site_v01'
        Class = 'sms_DistributionDPStatus'
        Filter = "PackageId LIKE '%$($i.PackageId)%'"
    }
    Get-WmiObject @Params | Select-Object -Property Name
}
```

If you're not going to use wildcards, using the `LIKE` WQL comparison is unnecessary.

Comment: @jcaloy if my answer solved your question, kindly mark it as such below the vote counter.